# Binding WPF-TreeColumn to Collection-Item

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I hope somebody can help me with this one. I'm currently
refactoring the GUI of an existing application using WPF
and DevExpress XPF Suite.

As it is a refactoring task, the models are already set and 
in a lot of our business-objects i have a structure like the 
following:

```
class BusinessObject
{
    var someFieldFromDB_1;
    var someFieldFromDB_2;

    UserDefinedFieldHandler handler;
}

class UserDefinedFieldHandler
{
    Dictionary<string columnName, string columnValue>

    string GetValue(string columnName)
    {
       //return value for column-name
    }
}
```

Is there any way of binding a treelistcolumn to the GetValue()-method
providing its name as parameter? to further complicate the issue,I need to accomplish this in code-behind as the grid columns obviously have to be
created dynamically.

thanks for your thoughts

EDIT:
okay, I got to solve this myself. I ended up exposing the dictionary public
and set the binding as follows

```
Binding myBinding = new Binding();
myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("columnsDictionary[" + ColumnDefinition.TargetDictionaryKey + "]");
...
treeListColumn.Binding = myBinding;
```